# Customize the Navigation Bar with MonoTouch by adding an image

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, uinavigationitem

Is there a way to customize the navigation bar with monoTouch?
I am trying to add an imageView to it but unfortunately it doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
imageView = new UIImageView();
var image = UIImage.FromFile("image.png");
var small = image.Scale (new SizeF (35f, 35f));
imageView.Image = small;
NavigationItem.TitleView = imageView;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did it. I messed up with passing the image to the view.
This is how it works.

```
var image = UIImage.FromFile("image.png");
var small = image.Scale (new SizeF (35f, 35f));
UIImageView imageView = new UIImageView(small)
NavigationItem.TitleView = imageView;
```

Comment: In which event did this go? I tried it in the ViewWillAppear without success